# image sprite hover effect

Tags: image, sprite

I'm trying to create a very simple hover effect for some buttons using image sprites. I followed the instructions given in an online tutorial but instead of the subtle hover effect shown in the demo there I'm getting a scrolling or roll-over effect so it looks as if the whole image is being replaced. I know that is what's happening but it's not supposed to look like that.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you share the code you tried, or link to to tutorial you followed.

Comment: the html I used was: '<a id="button" href="#">Click Here</a>'

Comment: What .css were you styling the #button with?

Comment: Hi, I am using the image sprites for a button (#button)

Comment: You haven't said which method you are using or shown either JavaScript code or CSS used to implement that method.

Comment: Hi, the css I'm using is as follows: '#button {display:block; width:160px; height:40px; background: url('button.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}' #button:hover {background: url('button.png') no-repeat scroll 0 -40px transparent;}'

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a jsfiddle with the information you supplied and a randomly selected graphic:

http://jsfiddle.net/XK7ub/

When I hover it is switching between two parts of the image used for the background of the link.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XK7ub/1/) demonstrates a cleaner `:hover` with:

```
#button:hover {
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}
```

which doesn't need to re-specify the image. It could even be simplified to `background-position-y: -40px;`.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. The effect is the same between the 2 examples, but the second is the better way to format it. The problem I'm having is there isn't a clean transition between the 2 images. Anyway, I'm still working on it.